PrimeNG's multiselect is throwing an error when used with input signals
I have a Angular 18.1 application in which I am using PrimeNg 17.18.5 (which according to their documentation should be compatible with ng 18).  In this application, I have a multiselect bound to an input signal initialized with [].  The error I am getting is:
TypeError: visibleOptions.filter is not a function
    at EffectHandle.effectFn (primeng-multiselect.mjs:864:59)

Drilling down into PrimeNg's code, I found the error in the line marked with >>>:
constructor(el, renderer, cd, zone, filterService, config, overlayService) {
        this.el = el;
        this.renderer = renderer;
        this.cd = cd;
        this.zone = zone;
        this.filterService = filterService;
        this.config = config;
        this.overlayService = overlayService;
        effect(() => {
            const modelValue = this.modelValue();
            const visibleOptions = this.visibleOptions();
            if (visibleOptions && ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(visibleOptions)) {
                if (this.optionValue && this.optionLabel && modelValue) {
                    >>> this.selectedOptions = visibleOptions.filter((option) => modelValue.includes(option[this.optionLabel]) || modelValue.includes(option[this.optionValue]));
                }
                else {
                    this.selectedOptions = modelValue;
                }
                this.cd.markForCheck();
            }
        });
    }

When I breakpointed the app there, it seems that the visibleOptions, which should a simple list of objects, for some reason converts into an actual signal, hence the error.
Here is my component's markup:
<div class="field">
     <label class="input-label">Name *</label>
     <p-multiSelect [options]="tables()" [(ngModel)]="selectedTables" appendTo="body" optionValue="tableId" optionLabel="name" panelStyleClass="widthOverride"></p-multiSelect>
</div>

and the component class:
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-edit-table',
    templateUrl: './edit-table.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./edit-table.component.css'],
    standalone: true,
    imports: [...]
})
export class EditTableComponent implements OnInit {

tables = input<TablesModel[]>([]);
selectedTables = signal<TablesModel[]>([]);

...
the rest of the code
...
}

The tables input is provided by the parent component.  There is a lot of code in both components.  I have only included the code I think is relevant, let me know if you need more info.
Any idea on how to fix that error?

please share the code for visibleOptions and modelValue, they are needed to check further
